# Sort selected contacts as ordered in admin

Tags: twig, sulu

It's possible to sort contacts when using the [contact selection](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.2/reference/content-types/contact_selection.html) content type in SULU Admin.
However, I found no reference or example how the set order can be used in the respective display-loop.

How can I get the contacts in the set order?

Comment: Looks for me currently like a bug. They should be ordered here: https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/08e3c20938208fdcf76bd59ae4fce9615a2859bb/src/Sulu/Bundle/ContactBundle/Content/Types/ContactSelection.php#L53 but actually aren't. Please create an issue on github for it or maybe create a PR to order them there by the given ids order.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I created an issue in github for it https://github.com/sulu/sulu/issues/5857
If you would add your comment as an answer, I will gladly accept it.